# MySQL unique key is not used as an index for SELECT

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table that has a unique key constraint and I performing a select query on that table. MySQL does not use the index for the unique key for querying that. Why is that happening?

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
        column1 int NOT NULL,
        column2 int NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY idx_column1_column2 (column1, column2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
mysql> explain select * from foo where column1=1 and column2=1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | no matching row in const table |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from foo;
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| foo   |          0 | idx_column1_column2 |            1 | column1     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| foo   |          0 | idx_column1_column2 |            2 | column2     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I would expect here that the `idx_column1_column2` index be used for my select query but it's not why is that happening, how can I get it to use that index automatically?

Comment: How many records are there in your table ? If the records are very less, MySQL can sometimes prefer table scan over using index, as a faster/more performant approach.

Comment: if you expect mysql to produce the output in index order then that's not how sql works you need an ORDER BY to produce output in the order you want,